# Where is the temp folder?

Tags: macos, mac

I would like to know where is the folder of temporary files in system. For example, in Windows is the folder:

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrador\Configuración local\Temp

Comment: `launchd` and some other daemons use `/private/tmp/` and `/var/tmp` for temporary files and sockets. `/tmp` is a symlink to `/private/tmp`.

Comment: Thanks friend! What is the difference between /private/tmp and /var/tmp??

Comment: As a general rule, `/tmp` is wiped upon reboot, while `/var/tmp` is not.

Answer (score 33):

OS X generates a programmatic directory stored in `/private/var` and defines the $TMPDIR environment variable for locating the system temporary folder.

Using **Terminal.app**, type `echo $TMPDIR` or `open $TMPDIR` (to open Finder on that folder).

There you will find temp files stored by the Applications running.

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/581347/where-is-the-temp-folder-inos-x

Since OS X is based on UNIX, there are several types of temporary directories, in addition the the "system" one where it stores things.

- $TMPDIR which is generated like `/var/folders/xl/84p38nhj405frmrkdpqb3v9c0000gn/T/`
- `/private/tmp`
- `/private/var/tmp`
- `/private/var/at/tmp`
- `/private/var/spool/cups/tmp`

Comment: Isn't /var identical to /private/var?

Comment: If you run a `ls -la /` you will see that `var -> private/var`. My answer is from 2014, so I can't really tell if that was the case back then. Still `/var` is just a link to real folder `/private/var`, probably to fulfill unix's conventions.

Answer (score 2):

Your question has a false premise that there IS a "temp" folder. This isn't Windows, and the Unix architecture of Mac OS X is entirely different. Temp folder for what? For some low level junk, there's `/tmp` and `/var/tmp`. For Application preferences there's `~/Library/Preferences`, for Application caches and temp files, there's `~/Library/Application\ Support`.

A clearer answer would be possible if you specified the particular task you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I think the OP is not trying to accomplish any task but rather wants to understand how OS X works. He's specifically asking for the equivalent of `%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Temp` (`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp` on Vista and newer), not  `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temporary Internet Files` or the like. That's probably `/tmp` (symlink to `/private/tmp`) and `/var/tmp`, the difference being that `/tmp` gets wiped clean at startup. I wouldn't say  `~/Library/Application Support` and `~/Library/Preferences` are temp folders as apps use them to save persistent data like state and settings.

Comment: Are you saying that there ***isn't*** a temp folder?  Your answer would be refuted by this http://superuser.com/questions/581347/where-is-the-temp-folder-in-os-x  which also makes this question a duplicate.

Comment: @Allan Did you at all read my post?

Comment: @Alexander No need to be condescending towards new users. As you've listed out many examples of what a program might use a temporary directory for, you might as well list them all out in a style [like lucasarruda's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/131080/194611).

Comment: @Alexander, isn't /tmp identical to /private/tmp?

Comment: True! One is sym linked to the other. Idk why they both exist, though. It could be the case that the two firs used to serve different semantic purposes at one point, and got merged at some point

Answer (score 0):

`/tmp` is the general location for temporary files in Mac OS X, as well as most UNIX-like systems.

Comment: There is also `$TMPDIR`.

Comment: `$TMPDIR` is an environment *variable* that points to a temporary directory like `/tmp`, not a temporary directory itself. You can set `$TMPDIR` to any value you want (and it will work as long as the directory exists and has the sticky bit set).

Answer (score 0):

The temporary directory for user specific temp files is given by the environment variable TMPDIR. This is under /var/tmp On my Yosemite login it is `TMPDIR=/var/folders/11/d839g3h52m55ps0l8f621b8m0000gp/T/`

Comment: Note that this also changes periodically. I haven't found any consistent behavior, which I suppose is good, if what you're storing in these folders truly is ephemeral.